# byte getting read wrong from file?

Tags: java

So, I am trying to store 3 longs to a file, but it will a lot of data so I convert them to byte arrays and save them. My current method for saving them:

```
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path, true)) {
                    //Put the data into my format
                    byte[] data = new byte[24];
                    main.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Saving most sig bits");
                    System.arraycopy(ByteUtils.longToBytes(uuid.getMostSignificantBits()), 0, data, 0, 8);
                    System.arraycopy(ByteUtils.longToBytes(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()), 0, data, 8, 8);
                    System.arraycopy(ByteUtils.longToBytes(player.getTokens()), 0, data, 16, 8);
                    //Write data in the format
                    output.write(data);
                }
```

longToBytes method:

```
private static ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

public static byte[] longToBytes(long x) {
    System.out.println(x);
    buffer.putLong(0, x);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

The byte array gets saved to the file, but the first byte gets truncated. the print statement in longToByes prints 8 three times.

The original longs are:

-9089798603852198353, -5339652910133477779, 5992

If I print the byte array I get:

-127, -38, -116, 84, 97, -116, 78, 47, -75, -27, -67, -8, 11, -100, -2, 109, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 104 (24 bytes)

But in the file I see:
ÚŒTaŒN/µå½ø(VT symbol)œþm(nul)(nul)(nul)(nul)(nul)(nul)(etb)h
which is 23 bytes (the first box doesn't show in notepad++)

but if I read it using

```
bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader(file));
```

I see:

64, -38, -116, 84, 97, -116, 78, 47, -75, -27, -67, -8, 11, -100, -2, 109, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 104 (24 bytes)

-127 is replaced with 64 somehow.

I concat the byte with "" to print it btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `FileReader` to read raw bytes from file. Use `FileInputStream` instead.

The problem with `FileReader` is that it reads `chars`, not `bytes`, from the file, by trying to decode the bytes using some character encoding (the default one if none was given).

```
bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Alternatively you can use `DataOutputStream` to write long directly to an output stream and use `DataInputStream` to read from an input stream.

```
try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    out.writeLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
    out.writeLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
    out.writeLong(player.getTokens());
}

try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    long uuidMSB = in.readLong();
    long uuidLSB = in.readLong();
    long tokens = in.readLong();
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot that this causes a problem, thanks!

Comment: If you are going to write lot's of data, you should add a buffer to your streams to increase performance, e.g. `DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))` and `DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)))` respectively. Then you do not need to handle a buffer like your `data` array in your code manually.

Comment: The data is going to be written over time, like 150 longs at once, about 1-10 times an hour, is refactoring my code a ton worth the performance?

Comment: Nevermind, I need to append in the middle of a file, so a DataOutputStream is off the table I think.